# USB mouse not working every time I roboot my laptop 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, mouse

I installed ubuntu 16.04 few days ago.

However, every time I reboot my laptop the usb mouse does not work.

The only solution to solve this problem is:

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

This only fixes the problem temporarily. This problem happens again when I reboot my laptop then I have to type those commands every time.

Is there any way to fix this problem permanently?
Thank you

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting doesn't work?

Comment: I bought a new mouse and it is working now.